# how to add or remove class on li first child using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert jquery code into javascript in which when window height is less than 50 then add or remove class not added on li first child but other li child class added or removed.
show jquery code below

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >=50) {
        $('.responsive-header .social-icons .social-icon li').not(':first-child').addClass('hidden');
        $('.responsive-header .social-icons .social-icon li').not(':first-child').removeClass('show');
      }
   });
```

Comment: Here's a good reference: [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: Consider using a [`@media` query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('share').addEventListener("click",show);
    function show(){
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#social-icons > li:not(.share)');
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].classList.toggle("show");
            divs[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    if (e.target.scrollHeight > 50) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".responsive - header.social - icons.social - icon li:not(:first-child)").forEach(function (el) {
            el.classList.add('hidden');
            el.classList.remove('show');
        }) 
    }
};
```

I didn't test it but idea is like this

Answer (score 1):

Since classes are being removed and added the most simplest and reliable way to exclude the first `<li>` is to give it a class and place it **after** the class that it's excluded from.

Use [**MediaQueryList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) interface to listen for viewport height changes and fire a callback function when the MQL matches the viewport height.

```js
// Create a MediaQueryList 
var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-height: 50px)');

// Add a listener to MQL
mql.addListener(shortWin);

/*
- Callback function passes Event Object
- Reference the <ol>
- if the MQL matches the viewport height...
- Add class .short to <ol>
- Otherwise remove class .short
*/
function shortWin(e) {
  var list = document.querySelector('ol');
  if (e.matches) {
    list.classList.add('short');
  } else {
    list.classList.remove('short');
  }
}
```

```css
.short li {
  background: magenta
}


/* This CSS selector will always override .short*/

.short li.first {
  background: initial;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class='first'>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
</ol>
```